# Maximum number of primes $>5$ in a sequence separated by the same gap

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Start with prime $p$ then find the maximum sequence of primes 
$p+gap, p+2\cdot gap, p+3\cdot gap$ etc.
Looking at the first gaps I found:
\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
2 & 1 \\ \hline
4 & 2 \\  \hline
6 & 5 \\  \hline
8 & 2 \\  \hline
10 & 2 \\  \hline
12 & 5 \\  \hline
30 & 6 \\  \hline
210 & 10 \\  \hline
2310 & 9 \\  \hline
30030 & 12 \\  \hline
\end{array}

I checked all gap sequences with $p$ up to the first $100000$ primes.

I noticed two things:

1) Most Multiples of these gaps seem to have the same maximum.
For example 4 and 8, 6 and 12, but also 30 and 60.

2) There is a connection to the primorials so I also added the primorial gaps.
That was a success up to 210 but then the maximum dropped for 2310 and then increased again to reach a maximum of 12 for 30030.

Questions:

1) Is there a gap that produces more than 12 results?

2) How far should I check the prime $p$ for a gap to ensure that there is no new maximum sequence?

3) Is there information on research already done or existing theories for this problem?

Comment: Are you aware of the green-tao theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem

Comment: No, Thanks for the link.

Comment: @LeonSot, you may as well post that as an answer.  Or I will (and round it out) if you don't want to.

Comment: The jumping champions are also the primorials. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JumpingChampion.html
I need to check much larger primes.